# ROS download unable to locate package error

Tags: 20.04, ros

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I want to download ROS Melodic 
I have followed this instruction from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu).

After `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full` command terminal is showing:

```
Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to configure your Ubuntu repositories to allow `restricted`, `universe`, and `multiverse`. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) for a guide on how to do that.
2. Issue the following command into terminal to setup your computer to accept software from `packages.ros.org`

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
   ```
3. Setup your keys by issuing the following into terminal:

   ```
   curl -sSL 'http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookupop=get&search=0xC1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654' | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
4. Update your packages

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Now install:

   ```
   sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
   ```

Comment: These are just the install instructions. And they do not work as the package cannot be found (like the OP). Wondering if they have depreciated Melodic because I have no trouble installing Noetic.

Comment: @MikeWise Are ROS Noetic and ROS Melodic different packages? I don't think they have deprecated Melodic.. do you have any evidence to suggest they have?

Comment: Turns out only Noetic is supported under Ubuntu 20.04 (and thus WSL2), and only Melodice under Ubuntu 18.04, and that was causing the "Unable to locate package" error. Although you can hack the repository config files to override that limitation. Seems obvious now, but some how I read the install instructions multiple times and didn't notice that.